# Prove |f(x)−f(y)|≤M|x-y|

Tags: calculus

Im am trying to solve the question below however I am not sure how to start and was hoping someone could help me out.

Let $D$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^m$ $(m>1)$ and let be, that for any $x$ and $y$ in $D$, the line segment between $x$ and $y$ is contained in $D$ (we say that $D$ is a convex).

Now assume that $f\in C^1$ and that $M>0$ exists such that for all $x\in D$ we have $|\nabla f(x)|≤M$.
Prove that for all $x, y \in D$ we have $|f(x)−f(y)|≤M·|x−y|$.

Hoping someone can help me get started! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is $\delta f$? The gradient of $f$?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any given $x,y\in D$, by the mean value theorem, there exists $z\in \{\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y:\lambda\in[0,1]\}\subset D$ (by the convexity of $D$), such that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|\nabla f(z)||x-y|\leq M|x-y|.$$

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you so much for your help!:)